# How can I print specific integer variables in a nested dictionary by using Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

This is my first question :)

I loop over a nested dictionary to print specific values. I am using the following code.

```
for i in lizzo_top_tracks['tracks']:
    print('Track Name: ' + i['name'])
```

It works for string variables, but does not work for other variables. For example, when I use the following code for the date variable:

```
for i in lizzo_top_tracks['tracks']:
    print('Album Release Date: ' + i['release_date'])
```

I receive a message like this KeyError: 'release_date'

What should I do?

Here is a sample of my nested dictionary:

```
{'tracks': [{'album': {'album_type': 'album',
    'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'},
      'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
      'id': '56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
      'name': 'Lizzo',
      'type': 'artist',
      'uri': 'spotify:artist:56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'}],
    'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
    'id': '74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
    'images': [{'height': 640,
      'width': 640}],
    'name': 'Cuz I Love You (Deluxe)',
    'release_date': '2019-05-03',
    'release_date_precision': 'day',
    'total_tracks': 14,
    'type': 'album',
    'uri': 'spotify:album:74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'}]}
```

Comment: First show us the dictionary (or a sample of it, if it is big). Without seeing the data, we cannot say much than KeyError usually means that the dicionary does not have that key.

Comment: Preventive advice: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58683192/edit) your question! Don't put it in the comment!

Comment: I did! Thanks in advance @Valentino

Comment: You need to make sure that `release_date` exists as key in the dictionary iterated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted isn't syntactically correct; running it through a Python interpreter gives a syntax error on the last line.  It looks like you lost a curly brace somewhere toward the end.  :)

I went through it and fixed up the white space to make the structure easier to see; the way you had it formatted made it hard to see which keys were at which level of nesting, but with consistent indentation it becomes much clearer:

```
lizzo_top_tracks = {
    'tracks': [{
        'album': {
            'album_type': 'album',
            'artists': [{
                'external_urls': {
                    'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'
                },
                'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
                'id': '56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
                'name': 'Lizzo',
                'type': 'artist',
                'uri': 'spotify:artist:56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'
            }],
            'external_urls': {
                'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'
            },
            'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
            'id': '74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
            'images': [{'height': 640, 'width': 640}],
            'name': 'Cuz I Love You (Deluxe)',
            'release_date': '2019-05-03',
            'release_date_precision': 'day',
            'total_tracks': 14,
            'type': 'album',
            'uri': 'spotify:album:74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'
        }
    }]
}
```

So the first (and only) value you get `for i in lizzo_top_tracks['tracks']` is going to be this dictionary:

```
i = {
    'album': {
        'album_type': 'album',
        'artists': [{
            'external_urls': {
                'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'
             },
            'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
            'id': '56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
            'name': 'Lizzo',
            'type': 'artist',
            'uri': 'spotify:artist:56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'
        }],
        'external_urls': {
            'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'
        },
        'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
        'id': '74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
        'images': [{'height': 640, 'width': 640}],
        'name': 'Cuz I Love You (Deluxe)',
        'release_date': '2019-05-03',
        'release_date_precision': 'day',
        'total_tracks': 14,
        'type': 'album',
        'uri': 'spotify:album:74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'
    }
}
```

The **only** key in this dictionary is `'album'`, the value of which is another dictionary that contains all the other information.  If you want to print, say, the album release date and a list of the artists' names, you'd do:

```
for track in lizzo_top_tracks['tracks']:
    print('Album Release Date: ' + track['album']['release_date'])
    print('Artists: ' + str([artist['name'] for artist in track['album']['artists']]))
```

If these are dictionaries that you're building yourself, you might want to remove some of the nesting layers where there's only a single key, since they just make it harder to navigate the structure without giving you any additional information.  For example:

```
lizzo_top_albums = [{
    'album_type': 'album',
    'artists': [{
        'external_urls': {
            'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'
        },
        'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
        'id': '56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS',
        'name': 'Lizzo',
        'type': 'artist',
        'uri': 'spotify:artist:56oDRnqbIiwx4mymNEv7dS'
    }],
    'external_urls': {
        'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'
    },
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
    'id': '74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB',
    'images': [{'height': 640, 'width': 640}],
    'name': 'Cuz I Love You (Deluxe)',
    'release_date': '2019-05-03',
    'release_date_precision': 'day',
    'total_tracks': 14,
    'type': 'album',
    'uri': 'spotify:album:74gSdSHe71q7urGWMMn3qB'
}]
```

This structure allows you to write the query the way you were originally trying to do it:

```
for album in lizzo_top_albums:
    print('Album Release Date: ' + album['release_date'])
    print('Artists: ' + str([artist['name'] for artist in album['artists']]))
```

Much simpler, right?  :)

Comment: Omg, thank you very much! I really appreciate all your help. But I still cannot get the popularity score :(

Comment: There's no "popularity score" anywhere in that data.  Maybe there's someplace else you're supposed to be querying it from?

Comment: Actually there is popularity score in data, because of space limitation here, I had to delete that part. I want to share my data but I cannot. Do you have any recommendation for that?

Comment: If you can't share your actual data then I can't just give you code that'll work with it, but I did my best to explain exactly **how** I was able to figure out the data you did provide.  If you read that over and apply the same principle to the rest of your data I'm sure you'll be able to get it working.  :)

Comment: There's no way I can guess from that where it lives in your overall structure.  :(  Can you look at the data you have and figure out *which* dictionary `popularity` is a key of?  Please look carefully at the first part of my answer -- see how I formatted the dictionary to make it easier to read and understand?  You might have to do the same thing with your own data (on your own if it's not something you can link me to) so that you can see where `popularity` is defined relative to the `lizzo_top_tracks` list that you're querying.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked!!! Thanks a million @Sam Stafford